# How can I find the area inside two unsorted x,y arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration

I want to find the are inside the region limited by two unsorted arrays (x and y).
If they were sorted, I could just follow this [example](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html):

```
theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, num=1000, endpoint=True)
x = np.sin(theta)
y = np.cos(theta)
answer = np.trapz(y, x=x)
```

In which the x and y array are correctly sorted in a way that allows trapz to correctly function (even if endpoint=False).
However, in my data x and y are not sorted. I would like to find the area enclosed by x and y as given in the following example:

```
theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, num=1000, endpoint=True)

ii = np.arange(len(x))
np.random.shuffle(ii)

x = np.sin(theta)[ii]
y = np.cos(theta)[ii]
answer = np.trapz(y, x=x) #This no longer gives the correct integral.
```

Is there a way to find the area enclosed by the arrays without sorting by angular position? It doesn't have to be using trampz. Thank you

Comment: Yes, you can use [Convex Hull](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html). As you points are in 2D you need to query the `volume` atribute to get the area (due to the underlying algorithm assuming you have 3D points).

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to try [Convex Hull](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html), but ended up simply sorting the points by angular position and (under the assumption that points actually enclose a surface) just integrated using trapz. I include in this answer the method I used.

```
def integrate_contours(x,y):
    xx = x - x.mean()
    yy = y - y.mean()
    theta_2 = np.arctan2(xx,yy)
    yy = yy[np.argsort(theta_2)]
    xx = xx[np.argsort(theta_2)]
    
    return np.abs(np.trapz(yy, x=xx))
```